# Save a string in a data frame (row and column)

Tags: r, dataframe, time, output

I want to save a series of years in a unique row and column using the following code

```
> dput(K$year)
c(1928, 1934, 1936)

data_completeness[1,13] <- (paste(K$year, sep=",")
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, 13, value = c("1928", "1934", "1936" : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
```

I understand the error but I do not know how to solve it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sep=` use `collapse=`:

```
data_completeness[1,13] <- (paste(K$year, collapse=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
data_completeness[1,13] <- str_c(K$year, collapse=",")
```